# Sticky footer not working as planned

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, sticky-footer

I have a sticky footer that is working fine on a music site, however, when I click on the genre with the most albums it doesn't make the page longer and they overlap. This makes the links unreadable as parts of the image in the footer are behind them.

This is my code for the sticky footer

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -80px;
}

#footer, .push
{
    height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ASP.NET inserts the main content into a `form` tag, you have to set the `form` height to 100%.

Change your CSS to the following should fix the problem:

```
html, body, form
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**
In wrapper, you specify a negative space of 80px, and in the footer you specify a height of 60px. These should be the same values unless you have child elements not shown that are expanding the footer height. Try making those values the same (either both 80 or both 60, whichever fits the footer better).

Comment: Who ever said he is using ASP.NET?

Comment: This hasn't changed anything :(

Comment: @Rikudo I may be mistaken, but I believe the question originally had an ASP.NET tag, but Darin removed that tag in an edit.

Comment: @JaredB-W, your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. Contrarty to classic WebForms where tags might be rewritten and have autogenerated ids, in ASP.NET MVC you have total control over the resulting markup and CSS. So posting your markup and CSS would be sufficient => unrelated to ASP.NET MVC thus I removed this tag.

Comment: It's and MVC Music Store so I added the MVC tag, does this affect you?

Comment: @JaredB-W The fact that it is written in MVC is relevant to debugging your issue, yes. But that does not mean make this an MVC taggable question.  This question is specifically dealing with HTML and CSS, and has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC outside of the fact that it is your platform. That is why Darin (correctly) removed the tags, because this question has very little (if anything at all) to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: ah who cares? I thought it might be relevant. Like it really matters

Comment: @JaredB-W And did you try my suggestion in the update yet? Is it working or still buggy?

Comment: I'm working on it now, it hasn't changed anything yet but I have a feeling of what might be causing it even after the changes

Comment: That's all fixed now, Thanks Moses